# Java: Accessing Static Methods

Tags: java, methods, static

Can a non-static method be accessed from a static method?
And can a static method be accessed from a non-static method?

Answer (score 6):

A static method can be accessed from a non-static, but not the other way around.  If you're inside a static method, you can only access a non-static method if you have an instance of an object on which to call the method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can a non-static method be accessed from a static method?
   **No because an object is required to access non-static method and there are chances that an object is not available while accessing a static method**
2. can a static method be accessed from a non-static method?
   **Yes.**

Answer (score 0):

To access a non-static method, you need to have an instance of an object. If you are inside a static method, then you are **not** able to call non-static method, because, per definition, you are not "inside" an object (so you don't have any object to call this method on). You can however call non-static methods from static if you have a reference to the object you want to call the non-static method on.